# Google Kubernetes Engine CD CI with Git

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm relatively new to Google Kubernetes Engine and Google cloud platform.

I managed to use and connect the following services.

- Source Repositories
- Cloud Builder and Container Registry
- Kubernetes
  Engine

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm currently using git bash on my local machine to push it to Google source repositories. Google Cloud Build builds the image and creates a new artifact. Each time I change my app and push the changes to cloud repositories a new artifact is created. I would then copy the new artifact to Kubernetes Workloads Rolling Update

Is there a better way to automate this? e.g. CD/CI without

[image]

Comment: There are 2 tools which you can use to use Jenkins or Spinnaker for Rolling update and canary deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [rolling update strategy in your deployment spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) from the beginning.
You can then use [Cloud Build to push new images to your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts#deploying_artifacts) once the image has been built instead of manually going to the GKE console and update the image.